# Error referencing dom node in expression angular

Tags: angularjs

I am pulling xml into an angular app using [x2js](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js). I want to mix html into the content of certain elements, but this is making it difficult to pull that data back out for display. Here is an example of the xml.

```
<data>
  <title>Some title here</title>
  <desc>This is my <b>description</b></desc>
</data>
```

Using x2js I get this object

```
{"data": {
  "title": "Some title here",
  "desc": {
    "b": "description",
    "__text": "This is my"
  }
}}
```

Since I can't use `desc` as is, I decided to write some code to work around it.

```
$scope.getText = function(csspath) {
  return $($scope.rawXmlData).find(csspath);
}
```

Finally I bound the object to the scope and made my angular code do this.

```
<h1 ng-bind="data.title"></h1>
<p ng-bind-html="getText('data > title')"></p>
```

Angular responded by getting furious and told me this.

```
Error: $parse:isecdom
Referencing a DOM node in Expression
```

Is there a better way to achieve my goal? (besides switching to markdown since the client wants html *sigh*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you are getting that error. However, by default angular will not allow you to print any html-string. You will have to "approve" your html by using `$sce.trustAsHtml` method.

Example

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .run(function($rootScope, $sce) {
    $rootScope.getHtml = function(html) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
    }
  })
```

HTML

```
<!-- will not work -->
<p ng-bind-html="'<h1>a222sd</h1>'"></p>

<!-- will work as it is ran through $sce.trustAsHtml -->
<p ng-bind-html="getHtml('<h1>asd</h1>')"></p>
```

Live example http://jsbin.com/keraqazapo/edit?html,js,output.

#### UPDATE

Well, the error is below. `ng-bind-html` does only take a html-string to render. What you are doing here is that you, by jquery, return a dom element. Which is not allowed.

```
$scope.getText = function(csspath) {
  //Returns dom element
  //should return value of $sce.trustAsHtml
  return $($scope.rawXmlData).find(csspath);
}
```

Comment: ah shoot, I should have realized that. thanks for pointing me in the right direction!